# In Javascript why we use async await while we have promise.all?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript why we use async await while we have promise.all? I understand that because of chain of promises we use async await but we have promise.all there!? Really confused and stuck over here!

Comment: `Promise.all()` has no connection with `async...await`. Both are used in different scenarios.

Comment: `Promise.all` is a mechanism to wait for multiple promises to resolve whereas `async/await` is a different syntax for handling promises

Answer (score 0):

async/await makes an asynchronous code look like a sequential code, therefore more readable.

Follows an example of asynchronous function that sums two values obtained asynchronously, written using Promise.all:

```js
function sum () {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Promise.all([
           Promise.resolve(3),
           Promise.resolve(4)
       ]).then(values => {
           resolve(values[0] + values[1]);
       })
   })    
}
```

Now the same function written with async/await:

```js
async function sum () {
    const a = await Promise.resolve(3);
    const b = await Promise.resolve(4);
    return a + b;
}
```

As you can see, the second function is much more readable and concise.

Comment: My understanding is async await looks more clear and promise seems complex with chain of promises.